# How to: User Add/Remove from array in other ViewController?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an empty `userArray` in `viewController1` that will use Strings.
In a popup, `viewController2`, I want to have the possibility for the user to add or remove from this `userArray`.

I'm gonna use a `textField` for the user to add their string but what is an easy way for the user to see the contents of the array and remove from it?

How do I pass this data between the `viewControllers`, whilst making sure it gets saved, and what would you recommend me using for removing from the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a segue from `viewController1` to `viewController2`, you can use `segue.destination` and set the `segue.destination.userArray` property to whatever you want.

If you don't have a segue, and what you are trying to do is have a model shared between view controllers, one thing you can do is make another class with a static property `userArray` and access it that way.

As for array removal, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1641390-remove

Comment: Great answer thank you!
Unfortunately i encounter another problem now. When the segue performs and i get to my desired ViewController, the "back"-button in the navbar puts me back to the ViewController i just segue'd from and not to the ViewController it should be going back to. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: @Alvarsson can you please clarify? What I'm understanding from your description is that it is the intended behavior. Good luck :)

Comment: Ofcourse! So i actually have 3 ViewControllers, all using navigation controller. So the segue that i wanted to perform is from VC3 to VC2.
But when i get back to VC2 directly after the segue, the "back"button on the navbar(in VC2) directs me back to VC3 and not the main VC1.

VC Being viewcontroller. And if I forgot to mention something just ask.
Thank you @MihirThanekar

Comment: So you might want to check out popToRootViewController @Alvarsson it's a method of your nav controller. Look it up :)

Answer (score -1):

Write your Array outside of your ViewController Class. Then you can access it from other ViewControllers.

Example:

```
//ViewController1.swift


import UIKit

var userArray = [String]()

class ViewController1: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}



//ViewController2.swift


import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        userArray.append("A")
        userArray.append("B")
        userArray.remove(at: 0)   
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: No; this is a bad idea. Most of the time, if you're adding a global variable (i.e. not inside the scope of a class or struct), there's a better way to do it. In this case, the first part of @Mihir's answer is better.